# Call to \textipa{} (TIPA) in caption with XeCJK loaded exceeds TeX capacity

Tags: captions, xecjk, tipa

I often need to use the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) and CJK characters in the same documents. I've been using `TIPA` and `XeCJK` to do this without problems, putting the CJK characters directly into the editing window and typesetting with `XeLaTeX`.

However, under this configuration, using the `\textipa{}` environment in a figure or table caption results in a "TeX capacity exceeded" error when XeCJK is loaded.

This *only* happens when `\textipa{}` is called; in the figure caption in the MWE below, for example, if you replace `\textipa{E}` with `\textepsilon`, it compiles perfectly well. So it doesn't seem to be loading TIPA that is producing the issue, but rather using the `\textipa{}` environment specifically.

Avoiding the environment in favor of the "long" commands (like `\textepsilon`) is workable but annoying in some cases. Is there any way to use `\textipa{}` here and still have the document compile successfully?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{STSong}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline
二 & 五 & 七 \\
\hline
\textipa{t\super{h}0} & \textipa{fAIv} & \textipa{sEv@n} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The first row has CJK symbols like 五; 
the second row has IPA symbols like \textipa{E}.
} \label{IPACJK}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use TIPA at all and just enter your IPA characters directly in the source using a font that has the characters, e.g, Linux Libertine.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `\protect` before the `\textipa` commands in captions, section headings etc. See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736).

Comment: And in fact, given this question: [TIPA tone bar glyph missing with xeCJK](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/358118) my first comment should be taken as the only real option.

Comment: Thanks for the replies; `\protect` does work, so I'm inclined to say it solves the issue for my purposes.

I am still curious about the root cause of the issue, as someone who doesn't yet really get how XeCJK and TIPA get along with each other (or don't, in this case). Also given how specific the conditions for the failure to compile are.

Comment: I get no error with TeX Live 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get no error with TeX Live 2018.

For older releases, make the `\textipa` command robust.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\setCJKmainfont{STSong}
\AtBeginDocument{\MakeRobust{\textipa}} % not needed with TeX Live 2018

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline
二 & 五 & 七 \\
\hline
\textipa{t\super{h}0} & \textipa{fAIv} & \textipa{sEv@n} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The first row has CJK symbols like 五; 
the second row has IPA symbols like \textipa{E}.}\label{IPACJK}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I indeed have an older version, as it turns out. I'll mark this as my solution of choice, thanks.

Comment: It's still not really a good idea to use TIPA with `xeCJK`.